# dualshock 3 controller vibrates constantly on usb

Tags: 16.04, usb, gamepad, ps3

I just got a dualshock 3 controller and since my PC (Ubuntu 16.04.1 has no bluetooth I'm connecting it by usb.

The problem is that as soon as I connect it to my machine, although it is recognized (checked with jstest), the controller starts vibrating constantly.

I already tried using xboxdrv with `--rumble-gain 0`.

I also tried setting the gain to 0 with `ffset`.

Both did nothing and the controller kept vibrating.. any ideas?

Comment: same problem...and over bluetooth it is crazy slow.

Comment: Have you gotten any help with this? I also have the same issue.

Comment: Same issue on Ubuntu 16.04, but only on fake ShanWan PS3 GamePad - also tested a official controller on same PC. Using pair via Bluetooth works good (after use the bluez patched). Looks like a Kernel bug!? See: https://github.com/libretro/Lakka/issues/418

Comment: Any news? Same problem with a sony PS3 (model cechzc2e), maybe a fake?

Answer (score 0):

i have this issue with one of my ps3 controllers, but not another one. i am able to fix it by unplugging it from pc and plugging into ps3 for a few seconds, then plug back into pc. any time i unplug from pc, and plug back in, it will start vibrating again and i will need to redo procedure to fix again.

Comment: This solution need a PS3 but give information.